# How can I align the labels of the buttons on a setter bar to the button centers?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I tried to align the labels on the buttons of a `SetterBar`to the button centers. This is my code:

```
lis = {"1", "2", "3", "dsf"};
SetterBar[Dynamic[buttonValue], 
  Table[lis[[iteration]], {iteration, 1, 4}], 
  BaseStyle -> {Red, Alignment -> {Center, Center}}, {ImageSize -> {100, 50}}]
```

How do I get the labels of the buttons aligned to their centers? Can any one show me how?

Comment: I see that you have not Accepted any answers.  Please read [this FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: there are some syntax problems with the way you have written your options. `Alignment` is not an option for `BaseStyle`. Also no need to use `Table`. Just use `lis` or `{"1", "2", "3", "dsf"}`directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SetterBar[Dynamic[buttonValue], {"1", "2", "3", "dsf"}, BaseStyle -> Red, 
Alignment -> {Center, Center}, ImageSize -> {100, 50}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nine seconds! :-)

Comment: yeah just happened to pass by before shutting the computer down and having a beer :)

Comment: Enjoy, Mike. . . .

Comment: This answer works, but I have a small quarrel with it. According to the _Mathematica_ documentation, `Alignment` and `ImageSize` aren't valid options for `SetterBar` and the FrontEnd code editor agrees, highlighting them in red. I infer from this that users can not rely on these options working in the future.

Comment: @m_goldberg what you have noticed looks like a bug (red styling) or oversight in the documentation. `SetterBar` is ultimately just a `Grid` of `Setter`s and `Alignment` is a valid option of `Setter`.

Answer (score 3):

I would change the Table into a Map:

```
lis = {"1", "2", "3", "dsf"}; 
SetterBar[Dynamic[buttonValue], Style[#, Red] & /@ lis, 
{ImageSize -> {100, 50}}, {Alignment -> Center}]
```

gives a SetterBar with centered labels.